# query calender list so user cant book same date and time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, calendar, client-object-model

## Update

```
var context= SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists();
var targetList;

function createItem() {
    targetList =  list.getByTitle('AppbokningarList');

    var listItemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.newItem = targetList.addItem(listItemCreateInfo);

    var listItemTitle = document.getElementById('Textrubrik').value;
    alert(listItemTitle);

    var listItemCustom = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    alert(listItemCustom);

    var listItemFromTime = document.getElementById('timepicker').value;
    alert(listItemFromTime);

    var listItemtoDate = document.getElementById('datepickerto').value;
    alert(listItemtoDate);

    var listItemToTime = document.getElementById('timepickerTo').value;
    alert(listItemToTime);

    var listItemBeskrivning = document.getElementById('Textbeskrivning').value;
    alert(listItemBeskrivning);

    newItem.set_item('Title', listItemTitle);
    var result = listItemCustom + " " + listItemFromTime;
    newItem.set_item('EventDate', result);
    var result2 = listItemtoDate + " " + listItemToTime;
    newItem.set_item('EndDate', result2);
    newItem.set_item('Description', listItemBeskrivning);

   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(),
    collListItem, strViewXml;

    strViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Lt><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>";
    strViewXml += "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + result + "</Value></Lt><Gt><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/>";
    strViewXml += "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + result2 + "</Value></Gt></And></Where></Query></View>";

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(strViewXml);
    collListItem = targetList.getItems(camlQuery);

    context.load(collListItem);
    if (collListItem.get_count() > 0) {

    }

    newItem.update();
    context.load(newItem);


    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item Created: ');

}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Item Failed: ');
}
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your code as it's posted now... what are `newItem`, `listItemCustom`, and `listItemFromTime` and where do they come from? Also, your `camlQuery.set_viewXml` method doesn't insert the value of the `result` variable because the string isn't properly terminated  -- the query string should be `"...<Value Type='Text'>" + result + "</Value>..."` -- need a little more information to give an answer here :)

Comment: Have updates my code on the top @John-o

Comment: Ok I understand a little more now, but you'll need to post at least the success handler also (there is no `onQuerySucceeded` in your `createItem` function). Also, it looks like you might have just accidentally added a duplicate `executeQueryAsync` call -- since I'm assuming you only want/need to call and handle it one time.

Comment: I have updated in the top. @John-o

Comment: I used a different way to avoid conflicts for several ressources (in my case it's for a trainer, a room and an equipment). I used a special page that is called just after saving the event (with the "?Source=" in the URL): if a conflict is detected then a warning popup is showing and the user can either edit his event to change the dates or he can continue. That way it's easier to verify everything!

Answer (score 2):

First, the order you're attempting to perform the check vs the item creation in needs modified. You either need to check if a record will be valid, then submit it with separate actions -- or use something like an [Exception Handling Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549119.aspx) to detect if the new item would violate your rules as it is being created. I think performing each action separately is probably the simplest method to explain and implement.

Second, you should try cleaning your code up first to solve some basic sources of problems:

- Your `ItemCreationSuccess` method only sets the text of some element
  with an id of `message` to the empty string which could be why you're not seeing any alerts or other behavior
- You also have a some scoping issues: you're setting `this.collListItem` equal to
  `targetList.getItems(camlQuery)` but then you call `context.load` on
  an item called `collListItem` -- `this.collListItem` is not the same object as `collListItem` in your function. I would recommend reading up on some good [answers about `this` on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) as well as some on [implied global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909578/what-are-some-of-the-problems-of-implied-global-variables) to better explain what happens here.

Now let's tackle the first part of your problem; understanding if an item already exists that would overlap with a new request -- I used DateTime valued fields (like in the default SharePoint calendar list type) so that I can use numerical comparisons (greater than or less than) and highly suggest you do also instead of using text fields; you can convert them back and forth as you submit or display them on the page in your app.

```
function checkAvailabilityAsync(ctx, targetList, fromDate, toDate) {
    // consider adding and returning a $.Deferred() object if you are using jQuery
    var frDate = new Date(fromDate),
        tDate = new Date(toDate),
        camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(),
        collListItem, strViewXml;

    strViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Lt><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>";
    strViewXml += "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + tDate.toISOString() + "</Value></Lt><Gt><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/>";
    strViewXml += "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + frDate.toISOString() + "</Value></Gt></And></Where></Query></View>";

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(strViewXml);
    collListItem = targetList.getItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.load(collListItem); 

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            // anonymous success handler
            function() {
                // you don't need to use 'createDelagate' here because the variables
                // in the outer function are available here
                if (collListItem.get_count() > 0) {
                    console.log('there is already an event on this day');
                } else {
                    console.log('go ahead and create the event the user wants')
                }
                // resolve the jQuery.Deferred here if implemented
            },
            // anonymous failure handler
            function(sender, args) {
                alert("There was a problem running checkAvailability: \n" + args.get_message());
                // reject the jQuery.Deferred here if implemented
            }
    );
    // return the jQuery.Deferred.promise() here if implemented
}
```

Then to call this you would do something maybe in a separate function like this:

```
(function() {
    var myCtx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
        myList = myCtx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Calendar"),
        // notice 24 hour time format which is probably what you'll prefer
        fromDate = "11 Nov 2014 14:00",
        // or you can specify AM/PM like this
        toDate = "11 Nov 2014 3:00 PM";

    checkAvailabilityAsync(myCtx, myList, fromDate, toDate);
}());
```

Something to remember here, the `new Date()` constructor used in the `checkAvailability` function accepts [many different types of date strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), so play around with it some in your browser dev tools javascript console to get a feel for which format you like best.

Anyway, I acknowledge that this isn't a complete solution, but I think this will get you headed in the right direction.

I also highly recommend taking some of the JavaScript classes on [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/paths/javascript) (paid after the first few) or [MS Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Studies/SearchResult.aspx?q=javascript) (free -- particularly recommend ["Javascript Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners"](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/javascript-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners))

Comment: I have updated by code in the top, what have i done wrong? Get no error when adding double meeting @John-o

Comment: You need to use something like the function that I provided to check the availability of the the date first, then where I alert that it's okay to create the list item you could insert another function to actually create the item -- it is a two step process.

Comment: I am confused over the code you added, i will update my code in the top and say what i need to do with the code that i have

Answer (score 0):

John-M gives a good outline. After a lot of searching, I was able to use the code below to query a list and check if a time slot was already booked.

Here are the specifics for ensuring the timestamp is included in your CAML query.

```
    (function() {

            // using jQuery get the different datetime values on the form
            var dateValue = $($("input[id^='EventDate']")[0]).val();
            var hourValue = $($("select[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateHours']")[0]).val();
            var minuteValue = $($("select[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']")[0]).val();

            var dateTimeValue = dateValue + " " + hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + ":00";
            var fromDate = String.format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}T{0:HH:mm:ss}Z', new Date(dateTimeValue));
            // do the same 5 lines above for your ending datetime field
            // OR say you want to make appointments 30 min long
            var myDateTimeField = new Date(Date.parse(dateTimeValue));
            var myEstEndMinutesField = new Date(Date.parse(myDateTimeField) + 30*60*1000);
            var toDate = String.format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}T{0:HH:mm:ss}Z', new Date(myEstEndMinutesField));

        checkAvailabilityAsync(myList, fromDate, toDate);
    }());

    function checkAvailabilityAsync(targetList, frDate, tDate) {

    var viewXml = { 
       viewXml: "<View>" +
                "<Query>" + 
                "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/></OrderBy>" +
                "<Where><And><Leq>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>" + 
                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>" + tDate + "</Value>" +
                "</Leq><Geq>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='EventDate'/>" +
                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>" + frDate + "</Value>" +
                "</Geq></And></Where>" +
                "</Query></View>"
    }

    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('"+targetList+"')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" + JSON.stringify(viewXml);
    $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            headers: {
                 "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                 "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                 "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },

            // success handler
            success: function() {
                // in the outer function are available here
                if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                    console.log('there is already an event on this day');
                } else {
                    console.log('go ahead and create the event the user wants')
                }
                // resolve the jQuery.Deferred here if implemented
            },
            // failure handler
            error: function(sender, args) {
                alert("There was a problem running checkAvailability: \n" + args.get_message());
                // reject the jQuery.Deferred here if implemented
            }
    );
    // return the jQuery.Deferred.promise() here if implemented
}
```

Here are some helpful source articles I've found during my search:

- [This article explains why you cannot use toISOString() and how to
  use Today or Now in your CAML query.](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2017/01/caml-query-for-datetime-fields-and.html)
- [Making CAML query with REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208020/make-caml-query-with-in-rest-api-call)